# pymongo installation gives permission error

Tags: python, ubuntu, pymongo

I am new to ubuntu, python.

I tried installing pymongo with [this link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/installation.html#installing-with-pip)

got this error..

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo': Permission denied
```

How to rectify that..

Comment: obviously you need root permissions, sudo is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you need root permissions for doing this installation.

Options:

- use sudo or root account for installing pymongo
- use virtualenv for creating a Python sandbox where you can install arbitrary module without root right

Comment: i didn't understand the error since i am new to ubuntu stuf..Its working now.. Thanks

Comment: you did not understand the error? the error is obvious: permission denied...what is need to understand that?